# Getting composer package from git submodule

Tags: php, git, repository, composer-php, git-submodules

I am trying to implement a `repository` for my libraries which are repositories, and added as `sub-modules` of the main repository, so the development of each library can be separated from each other and the `composer require` have to look at only the main repository

My Repository structure is something like this

```
Main repositoey
    ----Submodule 1
    ----Submodule 2
    ----Submodule 3
    ----...
```

This structure is needed because if, i want to share the library to anyone, then they only have to add the main repository to their `composer.json` and not every single repository for the library.

I have tried similar thing using the branches and tags but,  that is not feasible when more than one libraries with same version, we can not create duplicate tags for different branches, which is possible for the submodules.

What i want to implement is

1. Create modules
2. Push on the bitbucket repository
3. Share the module internally with colleagues
4. They should be able to get the module by running `composer require vensor/module`
5. And they do not need to add another repository

I do not know this is the correct direction i am heading in.
Please guide me or suggest a better way to implement the same mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't like git submodules. It is better to create separate git repository and add composer package with [packagist](http://packagist.org)(public code) or [satis](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md)(internal usage).

You can create package and publish it then you can add it to require in your composer.json then if you modify package you don't need create a new 2 commits in main repository and in submodule.

Comment: OK, satis may be the answer to my question, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I've gone trough same problem and for internal usage satis appeared to be the best solution.